# initRelector is defined in multiple libraries

Tags: angular-dart

I'm trying to export my various component templates from a templates.dart file. For example `export './src/foo/foo_component.template.dart';`
`export './src/bar/bar_component.template.dart';`

The VSCode analyzer is complaining `"The name 'initReflector' is defined in the libraries
package:my_app/src/foo/foo_component.template.dart and   package:my_app/src/bar/bar_component.template.dart"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest only showing what you need from those libraries instead of exporting everything that is public:

```
export './src/bar/bar_component.template.dart' show BarComponentNgFactory;
```

If that seems too much of a hassle you could go the other way and just hide initReflector.